# equivalent of \let\phi\varphi in MathJax

Tags: macros, mathjax

I usually have `\let\phi\varphi` in preambles of my LaTeX files, for aesthetics reasons. Is it possible to do something similar in MathJax? I tried defining macros

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({TeX:{Macros:{phi:"\\varphi"}}})
```

but it seems to have confused MathJax (no math was rendered on the page at all). What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done should work, so I suspect something is typed wrong or in the wrong place in your file.  Here is a complete working example file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax Macros Configuration</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({TeX: {Macros: {phi:"\\varphi"}}});
</script>
<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
</head>
<body>
phi \(\phi\) and varphi \(\varphi\) should both be the same.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).